# Elasticsearch: mapping text field for search optimization

Tags: search, elasticsearch, full-text-search

I have to implement a text search application which indexes news articles and then allows a user to search for keywords, phrases or dates inside these texts.

After some consideration regarding my options(SOLR vs. elasticsearch mainly), I ended up doing some testing with elasticsearch.

Now the part that I am stuck on regards the mapping and search query construction options best suited for some special cases that I have encountered. My current mapping has only one field that contains all the text and needs to be analyzed in order to be searchable.

The specific part of the mapping with the field:

```
"txt": {
         "type" : "string",
         "term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets",
         "analyzer" : "shingle_analyzer"
       }
```

where `shingle_analyzer` is:

```
"analysis" : {
           "filter" : {
              "filter_snow": {
                  "type":"snowball",
                  "language":"romanian"
              },
              "shingle":{
                  "type":"shingle",
                  "max_shingle_size":4,
                  "min_shingle_size":2,
                  "output_unigrams":"true",
                  "filler_token":""
               },
               "filter_stop":{
                  "type":"stop",
                  "stopwords":["_romanian_"]
               }
           },
           "analyzer" : {
               "shingle_analyzer" : {
                   "type" : "custom",
                   "tokenizer" : "standard",
                   "filter" : ["lowercase","asciifolding", "filter_stop","filter_snow","shingle"]
                                    }
            }}
```

My question regards the following situations:

1. I have to search for "ING" and there are several "ing." that are returned.
2. I have to search for "E!" and the analyzer kills the
   punctuation and thus no results.
3. I have to search for certain uppercased common terms that are used as company names (like "Apple" but with multiple words) and the lowercase filter creates useless results.

The idea that I have would be to build different fields with different filters that could cover all these possible issues.

**Three questions:**

1. Is splitting the field in three fields with different analyzers the correct way?
2. How would I use the different fields when searching?
3. Could someone explain how scoring would work to include all these fields?